# PHP parsing of custom math expression MATLAB style

Tags: php, matlab, math, expression

What would be a good algorithm or at least some piece of code to parse and calculate some custom math expression?

For example:

```
abs(add(subtract(5,10),abs(add(2,4))))
```

Another example:

```
abs(add(add(2,6),subtract(7,multiply(-1,multiply(-1,5)))))
```

So that would evaluate to 5-10 = -5 and then 2 + 4 = 6. the absolute value of 6 is just 6. Then next operation is -5 + 6 = 1 and absolute value of that is 1.

So trying to find a solution to parsing something like this without using an eval().

Here is what I tried so far.

```
$expr = "abs(add(subtract(5,10),abs(add(2,4))))";

$expr_array = preg_split("/(subtract\()/", $expr, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach($expr_array as $key => $value) {
            $value = preg_replace("/(\)|\()/", "", $value);
            echo $value."\n";
    }
```

this only renders

> > absadd
> >     subtract
> >     5,10,absadd2,4

But still need a good method to parse through it and distinguish the operands inside the () for each. If it was a same format it would be easier.

I have thought of using preg_split to parse the string, also creating separate arrays one for operand and another for numbers but some of the number is an actual operand with numbers in it like abs(add(2,4). 
Ideas?

Comment: no real good approach yet, hence why i am asking question.

Comment: No responses yet, seems like this is a really difficult algorithm then

Answer (score 0):

You could try to process it using regular expressions and a recursive function.

```
$pattern = '/^\s*(.+?)\s*\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\s*$/';
```

Comment: the expression can be completely different will post another example of another expression, a regular expression would mean the format is the same but its not.